# Control order of stacked figure in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

My data is structured similar to the example below:

```
Quarter <- c("Q1", "Q2", "Q2", "Q3", "Q4")
Weather <- c("cloudy", "cloudy", "sunny", "sunny", "cloudy")
Duration <- c(16, 10, 12, 15, 14)
WeatherCondData <- data.frame(Quarter, Weather, Duration)
```

When I plot this data, the second entry for quarter two (`Q2`) is sunny however, isn't displayed in sequential order in the plot - cloudy is the second entry.

```
ggplot(WeatherCondData, aes(x = Quarter, y = Duration, fill = Weather)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "stack") +
  theme_classic()
```

How do I change the plot so that sunny is the top part of the stacked bar for Q2?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `stringsAsFactors = F` to disable auto factor conversion in `data.frame()`. Then use `factor()` with `levels` args to set the order.

```
WeatherCondData <- data.frame(Quarter, Weather, Duration, stringsAsFactors = F)
WeatherCondData$Weather <- factor(WeatherCondData$Weather, levels=c('sunny','cloudy'))
```

[image]

Comment: You don't need to use `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` prior to using `factor` to set the order of the levels.